# Not able to get value of data if it has <b> or <i> in Word Template using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word

I was able to read XML file and convert in Array successfully. Now I want to add formatting in data. For this reason I have added  and  tag in XML but I am not able to get value of tag if it has  or  or any other formatting tag.

Here is code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestClass>
  <TestObject>
    <Site><b><i>Whatsapp</i></b></Site>
    <URL>https://www.Whatsapp.com/ABC/</URL>
  </TestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Facebook</Site>
    <URL>https://www.facebook.com/XYZ/</URL>
  </TestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Twitter</Site>
    <URL>https://www.twitter.com/ABC/</URL>
  </TestObject>
</TestClass>
```

Code:

```
Dim oXMLFile As Object
Dim XMLFileName As String
Dim Sites As Object
Dim URLs As Object

Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Files\Test.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

Set Sites = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Site/text()")
Set URLs = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/URL/text()")

//Sites get only `Facebook` and `Twitter`
```

If I remove `<b>` and `<i>`, it will work fine and I will get value of all 3 elements.

Please suggest how to manage formatting while getting value from XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not allowed to use `<` or `>` inside a XML-Textblock. You have to "mask" them. Best will be to convert `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`

Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Background of the problem:

the XML parser read the whole structure of your file. Every tag (words enclosed in `<` and `>`) create a new Node inside the internal tzree. If you want to access a node you simply going down the tree.

In your example: If you want `TestClass/TestObject/Site/text()` the parser first create a tree like this:

```
TestClass
  +--TestObject
  |  +--Site
  |  |+--b
  |  |   +--i
  |  |      +--text=Whatsapp
  |  +--URL
  |     +--text=https://www.Whatsapp.com/ABC/
  +--TestObject
  |  +--Site
  |  |  +--text=Facebook
  |  +--URL
  |     +--text=https://www.facebook.com/XYZ/
```

then it follows your XPAth `TestClass/TestObject/Site/` and take the node

```
+--Site
|  +--b
|     +--i
|        +--text=Whatsapp
```

This node have no `text`. so its retuns an empty string